# disable submit input during processing order paid with Stripe or enable them if Stripe pop up window disappears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, stripe-payments, payment

I am working on a web php app that uses Stripe for online payments.
At the end of the order process I have two choices: "pay now with credit card" and "pay later with transfer".
If I choose the first solution the payment will proceed successfully but, before loading the next php page, the same page with the two choices continues to show itself for some seconds (after the popup stripe's window had disappeared).
If I click the second button ("pay later with transfer") the app starts another process of the already paid order, recording it as "pending payment" rather that "paid", because the button is active.
So I tried to disable the button on submit actions:

```
$(".credit_card").on("submit", function() {
    var self = $(this),
    button = self.find("input[type='submit'], button");
    button2 = $(".pay_later").find("input[type='submit'], button");
    submitValue = button.data("submit-value");
    button.attr("disabled", "disabled").val((submitValue ? submitValue : "Attendere..."));
    button2.attr("disabled", "disabled").val((submitValue ? submitValue : "Attendere..."));
});
```

This code works but, if I close the pop up window of Stripe, buttons remain disabled, so the only way is to reload the page.
I cant trigger an event to catch the closing of the Stripe window in order to let the buttons turn active again.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to add the **close** event of Stripe checkout popup.

You can [see here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#optional) the **closed** parameter of Stripe checkout config.

Here is an example:

```
   var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_....',
      ....
      token: function(token) {
          ........
      },
      closed: function(){
        //This method will invoke whenever the popup close
        //Using this method to enable you button again.
      }
  });
```